# Struts как избежать redirect страницы после выполнения Экшена

Tags: java, локализация, struts

Делаю локализацию со Struts, но не получается сохранить параметры в урле, которые идут после вопросительного знака: `?variable="something"`. Сейчас при выполнении экшена я беру ссылку с заголовка и вытаскиваю оттуда название глобальной переменной, но параметры после `?` теряю. Что возможно предпринять, чтобы сохранить параметры полностью?

Вот мой пример:

```
public class ChangeLocaleAction extends DispatchAction {

    public ActionForward russian(ActionMapping mapping,ActionForm form,
                                 HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)
            throws Exception {

        request.getSession().setAttribute(
                Globals.LOCALE_KEY, new Locale("ru"));

        return mapping.findForward(request.getHeader("referer").split("/")[3].split("\\.")[0]);
    }

    public ActionForward english(ActionMapping mapping,ActionForm form,
                                 HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)
            throws Exception {

        request.getSession().setAttribute(
                Globals.LOCALE_KEY, Locale.ENGLISH);

       return mapping.findForward(request.getHeader("referer").split("/")[3].split("\\.")[0]);
    }
}
```

Код в struts:

```
<action path="/change-locale"
            name="localeForm"
            validate="false"
            type="com.epam.testapp.presentation.action.ChangeLocaleAction" parameter="language">
    <forward name="success" path="/" redirect="true"/>
</action>
```

Answer (score 1):

Убери `redirect="true"` из форварда, может это поможет, а вообще Struts1 пора уже забыть, так как у этого проекта [кончился срок жизни](http://www.infoq.com/jp/news/2013/04/struts1-eol).